# How can I read this binary file from python, with binary file, text file, and code presented?

Tags: python, binary

I have a binary file, which is *.xyz, a binary plot3d format file. I don't know how to read it from python. I got no problems to open a txt counterpart of it, but how can I open this binary directly?

The binary file looks like (first 30 lines):

```
0400 0000 0a00 0000 0400 0000 7800 0000
0200 0000 2100 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000
2100 0000 0100 0000 0200 0000 0100 0000
1500 0000 0200 0000 0100 0000 1500 0000
0200 0000 0100 0000 1900 0000 0200 0000
0100 0000 1900 0000 0200 0000 0100 0000
1500 0000 0200 0000 0100 0000 1500 0000
0200 0000 0100 0000 1500 0000 0200 0000
0100 0000 1500 0000 7800 0000 3807 0000
0000 0060 3bdf ef3f 0000 0060 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f ac1c 5a64 3bdf ef3f
```

The counterpart text looks like (first 30 lines):

```
          10
           2          33           1           2          33           1
           2           1          21           2           1          21
           2           1          25           2           1          25
           2           1          21           2           1          21
           2           1          21           2           1          21
  0.995999991893768       0.995999991893768       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000       0.996000000000000     
  0.996000000000000       0.995999991893768       0.995999991893768     
  2.333463643677469E-003  2.333463643677469E-003  2.219304467294528E-003
  2.219304467294528E-003  2.105145290300329E-003  2.105145290300329E-003
```

Regard this, I got several questions here:

1: Is this the case that I need to firstly transform the binary into text information, and secondly read it like reading text file?

2: Is this the case that programming languages like python have the ability to transform the binary information into text information without knowing the format in advance?

```
with open('oldsurf.p3d', 'rb') as OldSurf:
    bn=next(OldSurf).split()
    BlockNumber=int(bn[0])
    print('There are ', BlockNumber, ' Blocks in total.')
    BlockDimension=[[0 for i in range(3)] for bi in range(BlockNumber)]
    ln=(BlockNumber-1)//2+1
    for li in range(ln):
        d=next(OldSurf).split()
        bi=li*2
        for i in range(3):
            BlockDimension[bi][i]=int(d[i])
        if len(d)==6:
            bi=li*2+1
            for i in range(3):
                BlockDimension[bi][i]=int(d[i+3])
    print('The Dimensions of Blocks are: ', BlockDimension)
    value=[]
    for line in OldSurf:
        for word in line.split():
            value.append(float(word))
```

This problem have been there for a long time, still didn't find a feasible solution, please, any feasible solution is welcomed, thank you very much!

Comment: No, you must know the format or else it's just meaningless. You either have to parse the binary data yourself or use some other solution. Note, "binary" just means "not text" but both text and binary are just bytes representing *something*.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't say the question correctly, I mean, when I parse the binary into text without really reading it, do i need to know the file format? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved the problem by myself, using FortranFile module:

```
from scipy.io import FortranFile
```

there are:

```
read_ints()
read_reals()
```

details:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.FortranFile.html